# backface-visibility: hidden not working in grid on Safari

Tags: css

I'm very close to having solved [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74177365/11020164), by nesting a 1:1 grid instead of using flex and `position: absolute`; however, while it seems to really, really work on Chrome and Firefox, on Safari my backface is visible:

[image]

Super curiously, in dark mode, it appears to briefly work properly, before the backside takes over:

[image]

How do I make it so that my "flipped" card only shows the correct content? [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=backface-visibility) seems to think `backface-visibility` has been supported in Safari ~ forever. Is this a new bug? Am I doing something wrong?

(FYI, I'm using Safari 16.0)

Fiddle:

```css
.flip {
  perspective: 600;
  display: flex;
}

.flip-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
}

.flip:hover .flip-content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.flip-front,
.flip-back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 24rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.flip-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .flip-front,
  .flip-back {
    background-color: rgb(30, 41, 59);
    color: rgb(226, 232, 240);
  }
}

.container {
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flip">
    <div class="flip-content">
      <div class="flip-front">
        <h2>Step 1:<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-back">
        <p>Maecenas justo purus, semper id feugiat in, ornare vel urna. Pellentesque maximus tortor metus, eu posuere velit ullamcorper sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue on Safari, and the janky workaround I came up with was to adjust the opacity of front/back on transform.  Seems to work fine in both Safari/Chrome, and appears to work with dark mode as well.

```css
.flip {
  perspective: 600;
  display: flex;
}

.flip-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
}

.flip:hover .flip-content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.flip-front,
.flip-back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 24rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.flip-front {
  opacity: 100%;
}

.flip-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  opacity: 0%;
}

.flip:hover .flip-content .flip-front {
  opacity: 0%;
}

.flip:hover .flip-content .flip-back {
  opacity: 100%;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .flip-front,
  .flip-back {
    background-color: rgb(30, 41, 59);
    color: rgb(226, 232, 240);
  }
}

.container {
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flip">
    <div class="flip-content">
      <div class="flip-front">
        <h2>Step 1:<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-back">
        <p>Maecenas justo purus, semper id feugiat in, ornare vel urna. Pellentesque maximus tortor metus, eu posuere velit ullamcorper sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```